# Cannot install wireless driver for Broadcom 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, wubi

I just installed Wubi on a Dell Inspiron, and am trying to install the drivers for a Broadcom BCM4312 driver.  I know this is a common question on the site, but I think I have tried every solution posed, and I still cannot get it to work.  When I go into the jockey file, I get:

```
2013-08-24 17:10:10,049 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
```

I went into the blacklist.conf file and commented out

```
# blacklist bcm43xx
```

And I have restarted, even done a fresh install of Wubi.  Nothing works.  Any suggestions?  Let me know know what further info I need to provide.

---

Based on request for further feedback, I ran this command:

```
lspci --n -d 1434:
```

And got the response:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

For further information, I uninstalled wubi and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a new partition of my hard drive (I thought that might help with the driver issues), but I'm having the same problem.

I am able to connect an ethernet cable to get internet directly onto the machine.  And, when I had Wubi installed in a previous installation on the same machine, I was able to somehow get the wireless to work, so I'm pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: For jockey to work, it needs an active internet connection, was it available?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Comment: Better would be to read the answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) the first and the second (from top to bottom) and add some additional info to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a bug reported years ago https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/511379

This is what you can try

**Solution 1**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot

**Solution 2**

Remove bcm-kernel-source, if present

```
sudo apt-get purge bcm-kernel-source
```

Make sure you got this installed (otherwise, install it)

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```

Then, run

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep '8180|acx|at76|ath|b43|bcm|CX|eth|ipw|irmware|isl| lbtf|orinoco|ndiswrapper|NPE|p54|prism|rtl|rt2|rt3 |rt6|rt7|witch|wl'
```

If you see something like this

```
blacklist bcm43xx
```

Then

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

If you don't have this anymore, then add the # again, to look like this

```
# blacklist bcm43xx
```

Reboot

Keep in mind that this is a unfixed bug, so neither of these solutions might work for you.

Comment: I believe bcmwl-kernel-source is incorrect for his device. We need the identifier 14e4:43?? before we know for sure.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I started looking for solutions to this problems, and bcmwl-kernel-source appeared in all of them.

Comment: ...but the bug report was filed against BCM4311, and not BCM4312. I've been using `BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315]` with the STA driver for years, while b43 has been buggy.

Comment: chili555, I added further information in my answer above.  any suggestions?